# How to sign a document via api call?

Tags: docusignapi

How can I sign a document via API call without email client and UI interaction? Or if there is no way to sign, perhaps there is a way to force change status of a document?

I've seen many people asked for this and the answer was no, but all those posts are 2 years old. Perhaps there is a solution to it today?

It is possible to do everything via UI, but it is a terrible idea to spend time on an external service instead of your system under test.

Some say it defeats the purpose as the signer must view the document first, yes, but it is irrelevant, I simply want to test the flow of the system under test.

Please advise!

Answer (score 0):

For testing purposes, you do not need to unit test the DocuSign signing ceremony since we test it all of the time. Instead, test that your API calls create the  DocuSign envelope correctly.

For example, after your application creates the DocuSign envelope, your tests can interrogate DocuSign (via the API) that the envelope exists, is ready to be signed, etc.

If you're using embedded signing, you can test that your app can successfully obtain the URL for the signing via the DocuSign API.

For an end to end test, test software is available (from test software organizations) to interact with a web browser as a human does. Only test envelopes can be "signed" in this way.

For production signing of documents, the DocuSign signature appliance supports programmatic signing of documents using standards-based signatures (digital signatures). Your workflow must be authorized to sign documents on behalf of the signer.

For example, programmatically signing invoices sent by a company to its customers.

Comment: So the short answer is no? You cannot sign documents nor change the status of a document via api call even for testing purposes?

Comment: @Sunguresat -- correct, the short answer is no. You can change the status of an envelope programmatically but not to a status that indicates that a signer signed.